# SQL Server - Ways of renaming a table name

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I want to rename a table in SQL Server. I know the proper syntax would be:

```
sp_rename 'old table name','new table name';
```

Would it make any difference if I write it this way?:

```
EXEC sp_rename 'old table name','new table name';
```

I tried running it on SQL Server and without the `EXEC`, it would highlight my syntax `sp_rename` with red, but it doesn't throw any error.

Can anyone suggest the proper way or any other alternatives to rename a table?

Note: I know altering table name will affect or probably break the script and stored procedure, is there any way to prevent this? Or it only breaks if there is another table dependent on it?

Comment: if you have other sql statement within the same query window, you will need to use `exec`. Your first statement (without exec) works only if it is executed by itself

Comment: So if I want to rename,say 40 tables inside 1 SQL script, I should add EXEC to every 40 statements ?

Comment: Yes. You need to

Comment: Are you sure? According to Jaya, he said it's not mandatory.

Comment: why don't you try it out yourself

Comment: YOU ARE RIGHT man

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can execute a stored procedure with or without the EXEC Keyword. So Both your approaches are correct and has the same effect.

All the below 3 approaches are valid but the most commonly used is the 1st one

```
EXEC sp_rename 'old table name','new table name';

EXECUTE sp_rename 'old table name','new table name';

sp_rename 'old table name','new table name';
```

Comment: What if I want to rename a few tables in the same query editor window, do I still need to include EXEC?

Comment: No, But each rename should be called separately. EXEC is not madatory

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to right click on the table name and click "rename". Both of your methods of using a proc are correct, though.

I would caution using this procedure though, especially in renaming stored procedures. It has been documented [in many places](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/09/28/sql-server-renaming-stored-procedure-does-not-update-sysprocedures/) that sp_rename fails to update the sys.procedures table which is often used to identify these objects within your database.

Comment: So it's safer to use sp_rename "" , "" ?

Comment: You're fine doing it your way for tables. But for procedures, you'd want to drop and create to